# Oracle SQL - views

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the code originally:

```
    WITH counter(id, total) AS (
    SELECT stu.studentid AS "ID", count(stu.studentid) AS "Count of 
    Placement"
    FROM tn.student stu
    JOIN tn.event_result e on stu.studentid = e.studentid
    WHERE stu_sex = 'M' AND finalplacement = 1 
    GROUP BY stu.studentid )
    SELECT stu_firstname AS "First Name", stu_lastname AS "Last Name", 
    stu_sex AS "Sex", 
    stu_phonenumber AS "Phone Number", total AS "Count of Placement"
    FROM tn.student S
    JOIN counter
    ON counter.id = s.studentid
    ORDER BY total DESC;
```

This is the view created by removing the `stu_sex = 'm'`:

```
    CREATE VIEW Lubeina_view AS
    WITH counter(id, total) AS (
    SELECT stu.studentid AS "ID", count(stu.studentid) AS "Count of Placement"
    FROM tn.student stu
    JOIN tn.event_result e on stu.studentid = e.studentid
    WHERE finalplacement = 1 
    GROUP BY stu.studentid )
    SELECT stu_firstname AS "First Name", stu_lastname AS "Last Name", stu_sex 
    AS "Sex", 
    stu_phonenumber AS "Phone Number", total AS "Count of Placement"
    FROM tn.student S
    JOIN counter
    ON counter.id = s.studentid
    ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Hi guys, I am working with Oracle SQL. I am trying to output this by using VIEWS:

[image: ORACLE SQL]

The problem that I am having is that I am unable to write a command that outputs just the sex M gender or F gender

I tried using this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM lubeina_view 
WHERE stu_sex = 'M';
```

But I got an error saying:

> Invalid identifier.

Please help! I am not sure what command would output the data shown in the picture

Comment: views should NOT contain an `order by` clause...  ordering should be done in the FINAL query (that uses the view) .

Comment: Hi. There is misprint. In query your field  named "stu_sex". But in view it is just "Sex" .  Chech pls if it only on stack overflow or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL code in the question uses `stu_sex AS "Sex"` and later you use the query:

```
select * from Lubeina_view where sex = 'M'
```

which failed, but if you used:

```
select * from Lubeina_view where "Sex" = 'M'
```

it would work.

The problem I believe is case sensitivity. In Oracle if you define a column name with quotes it becomes case sensitive. I STRONGLY recommend you avoid using spaces in column names, and do NOT use quotes.

```
CREATE VIEW Lubeina_view
AS
WITH counter (id, total)
AS (
    SELECT
        stu.studentid          AS ID
      , COUNT( stu.studentid ) AS Count_of_Placement
    FROM tn.student stu
    JOIN tn.event_result e ON stu.studentid = e.studentid
    WHERE finalplacement = 1
    GROUP BY
        stu.studentid
)
SELECT
    stu_firstname   AS First_Name
  , stu_lastname    AS Last_Name
  , stu_sex         AS Sex
  , stu_phonenumber AS Phone_Number
  , total           AS Count_of_Placement
FROM tn.student S
JOIN counter ON counter.id = s.studentid
;
```

Now you can use `where sex = 'M'` or  `where Sex = 'M'` or `where sEx = 'M'`

Also urge you to NOT include `order by` in views.

---

> ```
> CREATE TABLE student(
>    stu_firstname   VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   ,stu_lastname    VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
>   ,stu_sex         VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
>   ,stu_phonenumber VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
>   ,total           INTEGER  NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO student(stu_firstname,stu_lastname,stu_sex,stu_phonenumber,total) VALUES ('fiendis','plan','M','555 1234',100);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW Lubeina_view
> AS
> SELECT
>     stu_firstname   AS First_Name
>   , stu_lastname    AS Last_Name
>   , stu_sex         AS "Sex"
>   , stu_phonenumber AS Phone_Number
>   , total           AS Count_of_Placement
> FROM student
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from Lubeina_view
> where sex = 'M'
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-00904: "SEX": invalid identifier
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from Lubeina_view
> where "Sex" = 'M'
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | Sex | PHONE_NUMBER | COUNT_OF_PLACEMENT
> :--------- | :-------- | :-- | :----------- | -----------------:
> fiendis    | plan      | M   | 555 1234     |                100
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW Lubeina_view_2
> AS
> SELECT
>     stu_firstname   AS First_Name
>   , stu_lastname    AS Last_Name
>   , stu_sex         AS Sex
>   , stu_phonenumber AS Phone_Number
>   , total           AS Count_of_Placement
> FROM student
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from Lubeina_view_2
> where seX = 'M'
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SEX | PHONE_NUMBER | COUNT_OF_PLACEMENT
> :--------- | :-------- | :-- | :----------- | -----------------:
> fiendis    | plan      | M   | 555 1234     |                100
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from Lubeina_view_2
> where sEx = 'M'
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SEX | PHONE_NUMBER | COUNT_OF_PLACEMENT
> :--------- | :-------- | :-- | :----------- | -----------------:
> fiendis    | plan      | M   | 555 1234     |                100
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=08b423fe1add3332eff0550fa5aad6ef)*

Comment: I tried to run the code you gave but I got an error saying FROM keyword not found where expected and I feel like maybe it is because of the quotes missing.

Comment: Please retry, I had a space where it should not have been. In Oracle just avoid spaces in column names - always!

Comment: Okay, I was able to run the command and create the view but unfortunately I got the same error saying invalid identifier when i ran: select * from Lubeina_view where Sex = 'M';           This is the error: ORA-00904: "SEX": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action

Comment: I can only suggest that you haven't done something I suggested or some other problem is at hand, please try this [online demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=84d73a56bb8b72d4e6bd6b2e996ca38f) try ityourself, change sex to Sex or SEx or sEx in the where clause

Comment: Please look at this (different) url [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=08b423fe1add3332eff0550fa5aad6ef) if this does not convince you I'm not sure how to explain any better.